# Many intents refers to same activity, how to know which one of them is launching that activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have four activites (add, find, edit and detail case activity). First tree referes with their intents to detail case activity. How to know which one of them launched my detailActivity and how to send case ID to detailActivity?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Usually you can send the string with the intent. You can identify string for each activity and send it with the intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes multiple activities can refer to the same activity. Your question is how to know which of the three activities opened the common one (the fourth one).

**First case:(from add activity to detail case activity)**

when you start an intent from add to detail case just put an extra string that will tell the other activity from where you came, something like that

add this code in (any activity) when you want to open the (detailcase activity)

```
Intent intent=new Intent(add.this,detailcase.class);
//now add the extra

intent.putextra("from","any");

//edit: add your caseid here

 intent.putextra("caseid",caseid);

//open the activity
startActivity(intent);
```

until now we started an intent that will open detailcase from any, we added an extra that contains a key: called "from" and a value:"any".

now do the exact same thing for all the other activities

**Second case:(from find activity to detail case activity)**

add this code in (find activity) when you want to open the (detailcase activity)

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(find.this,detailcase.class);
 //now add the extra

intent.putextra("from","find");

 //edit: add your caseid

 intent.putextra("caseid",caseid);

//open the activity
startActivity(intent);
```

**Third case:(from edit activity to detail case activity)**

add this code in (edit activity) when you want to open the (detailcase activity)

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(edit.this,detailcase.class);
 //now add the extra

 intent.putextra("from","edit");

  //edit: add your caseid

  intent.putextra("caseid",caseid);

 //open the activity
 startActivity(intent);
```

now the trick is to go to the Oncreate method of the detail case activity and add this

```
private string comingfrom;

//edit: add these also
private int caseid;
private int caseid_any;
private int caseid_find;
private int caseid_edit; 

//in on create method do this

comingfrom=getIntent().getStringExtra("from");

//edit: add this also
caseid=getIntent().getIntExtra("caseid",0);//0 is just a default value don't worry 



//check now from where you came like that

if(comingfrom.equals("any")){

 //then you came from any

 //edit:
 caseid_any=caseid;   //this is caseid from any

}

if(coming from.equals("find")){

 //you came from find

 //edit:

 caseid_find=caseid;  //this is caseid from find

}

if(comingfrom.equals("edit")){

 //you came from edit

  //edit:

   caseid_edit=caseid;//this is caseid from edit

}
```

all we did is get the value of the "from" key and we store it in a variable named coming from, finally we checked the value and we now know from where we came.

**EDIT**

Okay check the code snippets again when you see this comment

```
 //edit: ......
```

this means it was added.

And this how you pass caseid from each activity and know from where it came .

Comment: Ok, that's clear. But how to send my case.getId() to detail activity as well?

Comment: @jvoh what does case.getd() represent ?

Comment: ID of my object.

Comment: @jvoh I assume its a string found in each of the three activities

Comment: Case ID is int. In AddActivity when I add object do DB getDatabaseHelper().getCaseDao().create(case); I want to send id of that object to detail activity i.putExtra(CASE_KEY, case.getId()). Same thing I want to do from others activities (find, edit). So, want to send ID(int) and to know from which activity it came.

Comment: @jvoh glad to help.